# Django REST Framework Foreign Key - NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have the following setup in Django REST Framework:

**models.py:**

```
class Device(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    altitude = models.FloatField()

class Event(models.Model):
    id_device = models.ForeignKey(Device, related_name='events')
    name = models.CharField()
    date = models.CharField()
    time = models.CharField()

class Values(models.Model):
    id_device = models.ForeignKey(Device)
    id_event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name='values')
    x = models.FloatField()
    y = models.FloatField()
    z = models.FloatField()
    time = models.IntegerField()
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    

    events = EventSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'name', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'altitude', 'events')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        events_data = validated_data.pop('events')
        device = Device.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for event in events_data:
            Events.objects.create(device=device, **event)
        return device

class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    values = ValuesSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'name', 'date', 'time', 'values')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        values_data = validated_data.pop('values')
        event = Event.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for value in values_data:
            Values.objects.create(event=event, **value)
        return event

class ValuesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Values
        fields = ('x', 'y', 'z', 'time')
```

When I try to post an **event** with some **values** assigned using a JSON file like this one:

```
{
    "name": "name_example", 
    "date": "date_example", 
    "time": "time_example", 
    "values": [
      {
        "x": 1, 
        "y": 2, 
        "z": 3, 
        "time": 1
      }, 
      {
        "x": 10, 
        "y": 20, 
        "z": 30, 
        "time": 2
      }, 
      {
        "x": 100, 
        "y": 200, 
        "z": 300, 
        "time": 4
      }
   ]
}
```

I get the error `IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: drf_event.id_device_id`

I'm new to this framework, so what can I do in order to post new **events** with **values** assigned to an existing **device**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't a key pointing to device in your EventSerializer. You miss the id_device.

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    values = ValuesSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id_device', 'url', 'id', 'name', 'date', 'time', 'values')
```

And you need to add the key in your json:

```
{
    "id_device": 1,
    "name": "name_example", 
    "date": "date_example", 
    "time": "time_example", 
    "values": [
      {
        "x": 1, 
        "y": 2, 
        "z": 3, 
        "time": 1
      }, 
      {
        "x": 10, 
        "y": 20, 
        "z": 30, 
        "time": 2
      }, 
      {
        "x": 100, 
        "y": 200, 
        "z": 300, 
        "time": 4
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it was a great help! I also had to change this create() method code line to:  `Values.objects.create(id_device=event.id_device, id_event=event, **value)`